# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: Load report failed - VB.NET 2003

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Anybody know why the below error exist?

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: Load report failed
```

Answer (score 2):

From your comments about windows\Temp, that is caused by the application pool's identity not having access to c:\windows\Temp (and possibly to the reports folder).

You can solve this problem by giving the application pool credentials that do have the necessary permissions, or giving read write permissions to "Network User" to the c:\windows\temp folder (and again, possibly to the reports folder).

The reason why this folder is required is that the crystal runtime creates a dynamic copy of the report at runtime and places it in the %temp% folder. It is the temp folder copy (with a GUID appended to the original file name) that is shown in the web browser. This is by design and is a useful feature to ensure the live report is safe.

Following from this, you will have to do a proper cleanup after loading every report because **they just stay there and fill up the temp folder!**

Something like:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose(); // if using the viewer
CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
report.Close(); // I can't remember if this is part of the reportDocument class
report.Dispose();
report = null;
GC.Collect(); // crazy but true. Monitor the temp folder to see the effect
```

Comment: GC.Collect is still not a safe solution, this broke the ability to print, export or search the file.

Comment: @Steven hmmm, we learned the need for this crazy step the hard way working on a solution written in 2012, still shipping with thousands of reports daily. Without the sequence above, the temp folder filled up and the print limit was hit.

Comment: @Steven And, our solution was asp.net, so the page was rendered (or report was printed) so it was safe to dispose of report. Your scenario might be different, so schedule the disposal accordingly

Comment: I've tried using it again (Including the GC.Collect), it did worked to continiously create the report again, as it's disposed well. So that problem is solved. But the buttons on the toolbar of the rapport doesn't seem to work after using that function. I'm also using asp.net. No other solutions I've found are mentioning the functioning of the toolbar after trying out.

Comment: @Steven The toolbar buttons unfortunately don't relate to this. Once the page is served by asp.net, that block of code above runs in the Page_Unload event. Every action triggered from the toolbar will occur in a postback during the page load cycle.

Comment: You were right, At my side the Reportdocument was set during Page_Init(), but it's only filling in the Reportdocument during the `!postback`, I managed to get the buttons and your code working by also allowing the Reportdocument to load during postbacks. Thanks for helping me on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Reckface's answer was clear enough, but to add something up.

I managed to get it working using this:

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (reportDocument != null)
    {
        reportDocument.Close();
        reportDocument.Dispose();
        crystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Doing so may cause issues with the buttons on the toolbar, they can't find the document path anymore because the document is disposed. In that case the document needs to load the path again during postbacks: [source](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Crystal-Reports-13-Visual-Studio-2010-CrystalReportViewer-Search-Button-Issue---No-valid-report-source-is-available.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I want to add that I got this error because the report was not embedded into the class library.

Solution: I removed the report from the project. I restarted Visual Studio 2022 and than added the crystal report again. This time it was added as an embedded resource.

Answer (score -5):

Did you even bother to Google it?  This is a common exception; there are hundreds of posts about it scattered around the intertubes.

The Crystal .NET runtime has famously cryptic error messages.  This one just means that the .rpt file (or embedded report) could not be loaded. There are several possible root causes: wrong filename or path, security violation, you are not disposing of old reports properly and windows/temp is getting hogged up, etc.

Do some research.  If you're still stuck, come back and elaborate on the problem (do any of your reports work, is this a web app?, what code are you using, etc.)

Comment: yeah, I'll try to google it before I post a question here in stackoverflow. I'm sure that the report file name and report path is correct. What makes me confuse is why only 1 of our clien can't generate the report. I have also installed the crnet11win_en.exe but error still persist. What is my last option is about the permission on "windows/temp". Why should I do on this part?