# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException while initializing the reportdocument

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Error while initializing the report document which is inherited from crystal reports engine
and all attributes/ dlls throwing exception while initializing the report document
check the image for better understanding.
Thanks

[here is the Error Screenshot in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1EtH.png)

Comment: This thread may provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828111/crystaldecisions-crystalreports-engine-loadsavereportexception-load-report-fail#19539763